# Angular 2 with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently we have a Main application built in Angular 1.4 and it uses Twitter bootstrap 2.3.2

This application contains different components built with Angular 1.4 built by different application teams,

Further new components we want to create using Angular 2,
We would like to use Twitter bootstrap 3 with Angular 2.

My question is Since the main application uses Twitter bootstrap 2 my new Angular 2 component should use Twitter Bootstrap 3, I want my new Angular 2 component to sit inside my main app.

**Where should i include the Twitter Bootstrap 3 reference since I am already referring Twitter Bootstrap 2 in my Main Application Index.html**

I don't think it will be a good practice to use StyleUrl of Angular 2 to include Twitter BS3 and it will be duplicated across multiple components.

Please provide some design suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Few approaches can be:

1. Break the website into big components or pages, this will give you freedom to use the components/pages as per your wish, each component scan have its own style guidelines and its own JS framework.
2. Use themes from bootstrap 2 and bootstrap 3 and try to make you own css framework and then you can use it the way you want, most of the companies alter the CSS guidelines according to their themes. (this process may lead to many bugs, you have to careful)